# What is happening with these two arrays?

Tags: java, arrays

```
  int[] x = new int [] {1,2,3};
  int[] y = new int [] {4,5,6,7};

  System.out.println(x[0] + ", " + y[0]);
  x = y;

  System.out.println(x[0] + ", " + y[0]);
  x[0] = 42;

  System.out.println(x[0] + ", " + y[0]);
```

Output:

```
1, 4
4, 4
42, 42
```

Now my question is, why is y[0] 42 in the third print out and not 4? I only changed x[0], and the "x = y" came before that change and not after, so how is y[0] 42? I thought the program went from top to bottom.

Comment: Because of `x = y`. You're making `x` refer to the same array as `y`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays are not primitive values, they are objects. When you write `x = y;` the first array becomes unreachable and garbage collectable, and both variables now point to the second array. There is *only one* array that you are working with from now on.

Answer (score 0):

`x` and `y` both point to the same array. Changing the value of one of the elements in the array is going to be reflect through either references that you use to access the array.

Update: 
Take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html this will help you understand the concept of arrays in Java